# OpenCV - training LatentSVMDetector models in OpenCV (algorithm from Pedro Felzenszwalb )

Tags: object, opencv, detection, svm, object-detection

Why is there no module to train latent SVM in OpenCV?

There is only the detector: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/latent_svm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right. You should use the Matlab package to train new models.

However, unfortunately, there is no updated code that I know of for transforming the Matlab models to xml's to use in OpenCV.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to transform it? Is there any documentation regarding the structure of the models, so that I can write a piece of the code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I haven't search very thoroughly.